# Add days to Timestamp column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to add days to timestamp column but I'm losing the hours from the original timestamp column after adding days. Any pointers on how to retain the hours in the final output?

```
var Df = Seq(
(1, "2020-04-01 14:31:10",0),
(2, "2020-04-15 14:31:10",-1),
(3, "2020-04-16 03:31:10",3),
(6, "2020-03-01 14:31:10",30)    
 ).toDF("Id", "startDt", "Flag")

Df = (Df.withColumn("startDt",to_timestamp($"startDt")))

(Df.withColumn("newdate",when($"Flag".isNotNull && $"Flag" > 0 && $"Flag" <= 30
        && $"startDt".isNotNull, expr("date_add(startDt,Flag)").cast(TimestampType)).otherwise(lit(null))
                  )
).show()
```

Expected result:

```
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
| Id|            startDt|Flag|            newdate|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|  1|2020-04-01 14:31:10|   0|               null|
|  2|2020-04-15 14:31:10|  -1|               null|
|  3|2020-04-16 03:31:10|   3|2020-04-19 03:31:10|
|  6|2020-03-01 14:31:10|  30|2020-03-31 14:30:10|
```

Instead, given result:

```
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
| Id|            startDt|Flag|            newdate|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|  1|2020-04-01 14:31:10|   0|               null|
|  2|2020-04-15 14:31:10|  -1|               null|
|  3|2020-04-16 03:31:10|   3|2020-04-19 00:00:00|
|  6|2020-03-01 14:31:10|  30|2020-03-31 00:00:00|
```

I can get the desired output using an UDF, but is there any built-in function to achieve the same?

```
val AddDaysToTimeStamp = udf((x: java.sql.Timestamp, y: Int) => {val result = new Timestamp(x.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(y)) result})
```

Comment: @mck, getting an error, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
DataType interval is not supported.(line 1, pos 69)

== SQL ==
cast(startDt as timestamp) + cast(cast(flag as string) || ' days' as interval)

Comment: try edited answer? I used another way to specify the interval type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm losing the hours from the original timestamp column after adding days

That's because `date_add` always returns `DateType` (rather than `TimestampType`), even though it takes either type as input.

A couple of approaches using Spark API if using of UDF isn't preferred:

**Approach 1**: Convert to Unix epoch time and modify in seconds (*)

```
Df.
  withColumn("startDt", to_timestamp($"startDt")).
  withColumn(
    "newdate",
    when($"Flag".isNotNull && $"Flag" > 0 && $"Flag" <= 30 && $"startDt".isNotNull,
      to_timestamp(unix_timestamp($"startDt") + $"Flag" * 3600 * 24)
    )
  ).show
// +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
// | Id|            startDt|Flag|            newdate|
// +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
// |  1|2020-04-01 14:31:10|   0|               null|
// |  2|2020-04-15 14:31:10|  -1|               null|
// |  3|2020-04-16 03:31:10|   3|2020-04-19 03:31:10|
// |  6|2020-03-01 14:31:10|  30|2020-03-31 15:31:10|  <-- +1 hour due to daylight savings
// +---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```

(*) If the period of the added/subtracted days crosses a Daylight saving time, the hour value will be shifted.

**Approach 2**: Split the datetime string and modify date & time separately

```
Df.
  withColumn("splitTS", split($"startDt", "\\s+")).
  withColumn(
    "newdate",
    when($"Flag".isNotNull && $"Flag" > 0 && $"Flag" <= 30,
      concat(expr("date_add(to_date(splitTS[0]), Flag)"), lit(" "), $"splitTS"(1))
    )
  ).show
// +---+-------------------+----+--------------------+-------------------+
// | Id|            startDt|Flag|             splitTS|            newdate|
// +---+-------------------+----+--------------------+-------------------+
// |  1|2020-04-01 14:31:10|   0|[2020-04-01, 14:3...|               null|
// |  2|2020-04-15 14:31:10|  -1|[2020-04-15, 14:3...|               null|
// |  3|2020-04-16 03:31:10|   3|[2020-04-16, 03:3...|2020-04-19 03:31:10|
// |  6|2020-03-01 14:31:10|  30|[2020-03-01, 14:3...|2020-03-31 14:31:10|
// +---+-------------------+----+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Note that validation of the `startDt` string (e.g. via a Regex timestamp pattern matching) could be added, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a interval to the timestamp, where the interval is constructed from the `flag` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df2 = Df.withColumn(
    "newdate", 
    when(
        $"Flag".isNotNull && $"Flag" > 0 && $"Flag" <= 30 && $"startDt".isNotNull, 
        $"startDt" + concat($"flag".cast("string"), lit(" days")).cast(CalendarIntervalType)
    )
)

df2.show
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
| Id|            startDt|Flag|            newdate|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
|  1|2020-04-01 14:31:10|   0|               null|
|  2|2020-04-15 14:31:10|  -1|               null|
|  3|2020-04-16 03:31:10|   3|2020-04-19 03:31:10|
|  6|2020-03-01 14:31:10|  30|2020-03-31 14:31:10|
+---+-------------------+----+-------------------+
```